# An unexpected Region inside of a ButtonBar

Tags: javafx, tornadofx

In my TornadoFX (which is a wrapper to JavaFX8) app I create a ButtonBar with one button. I use the DSL (code, not XML) for that.

Unexpectedly, all my buttons are squashed on the right. Scenic View shows that there is a Region before all my buttons with `Hgrow = Always`.

- Where does this Region come from?
- How do I remove it / set to  `Hgrow = Never`?
- How in general do i get references to the children of a ButtonBar? `GetChildrenUnmodifiable` returns an empty list.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `ButtonBar` is supposed to do. According to the [ButtonBar docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBar.html):

> A ButtonBar is essentially a HBox, **with the additional functionality for operating system specific button placement**.

**emphasis mine*

The button bar will add regions to push the buttons to where they are expected to be on your OS. To change where the buttons end up on the bar, you use [`ButtonBar.setButtonData(Button, ButtonData)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBar.html#setButtonData-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar.ButtonData-).

Comment: How do I reduce this region to zero? My buttons are not standard.

Comment: There isn't a way as far as I know. Your best bet would be to use an `HBox` and style it appropriately. Or just set them all to be `ButonData.LEFT`. Note that, when using a `ButtonBar`, the ordering of buttons can change across OSs too.

Comment: That works to some extend. What about getting the buttons? Any short way?

Comment: Can't you just do `getButtons()`?

Comment: Ow, yes I can! The Kotlin autocomplete played a bad joke with me ((